# Could someone tell me the difference between these two MongoDB queries

Tags: mongodb

I was given the following problem in MongoDB:

How many companies in the sample_training.companies dataset were

1. (Either founded in 2004 && ( either have the social category_code [or] web category_code))
   || (founded in the month of October && ( either have the social category_code [or] web category_code))

The actual query for the above question is given below and it returned 149 documents.

**CorrectQuery:**

```
db.companies.find({
  "$or":[
    {
      "founded_year":2004,
      "$or":[
        { "category_code":"social" },
        { "category_code":"web" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "founded_month":10,
      "$or":[
        { "category_code":"social" },
        { "category_code":"web" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}).count()
```

But I've tried to formulate another query for the same problem, unfortunately, it returned the incorrect value of 668 rows.

**Incorrect Query:**

```
db.companies.find({
  "$or":[
    {"category_code":"social"},
    {"category_code":"web"}
  ],
  "$or":[
    {"founded_year":2004},
    {"founded_month":10}
  ]
}).count()
```

Could someone help me in understanding the difference between these queries?

Comment: I've updated your question from asking about `MangoDB` - an ORM on the Kohana framework to asking about `MongoDB`. The question seems to be `MongoDB`-specific, with nothing related to `MangoDB`. If my edit's incorrect, and you're using the outdated Kohana framework on PHP, add the relevant Kohana code and change the tag back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just the standard order of operations in boolean logic.

`AND` has priority over `OR` in the same way that multiplication has priority over addition in mathematics.

The first example is correct because the logic matches the logic in your problem.

The second example logic is:

```
(category_code is "social" or category_code is "web") and (founded_year is 2004 or founded_month is 10)
```

Your second example:

```
db.companies.find({
  "$or":[
    {"category_code":"social"},
    {"category_code":"web"}
  ],
  "$or":[
    {"founded_year":2004},
    {"founded_month":10}
  ]
}).count()
```